# Split string array

Tags: c#-4.0

Break a String array of size 5 into two parts 2 & 3 string arrays?

Orignal

```
String Array[] = {"asjjsjamsssssssssssssssssssssss",
                  "hcb j m dnfijvkfkjvkjdffkbdfblllfl",
                  "bjbvfumfkkf md",
                  "jdsjvjsdjvjjjjdjjdj",
                  "bsdjdddddddddddddddddddddddd"}
```

Resulting String contains 2 & 3 strings.

Comment: What is your desired output? `"hcb md"`?

Comment: The quickest way is to not do it.  With ArraySegment<>

Answer (score 1):

Try this below.

```
    string[] arr  = {"asjjsjamsssssssssssssssssssssss",
                               "hcb j m dnfijvkfkjvkjdffkbdfblllfl",
                                "bjbvfumfkkf md",
                                "jdsjvjsdjvjjjjdjjdj",
                                  "bsdjdddddddddddddddddddddddd"};

var first = arr.Take(2).ToArray();
var second = arr.Skip(2).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 just for understanding the question :-)  It did not make sense to me until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to break string array unless the number of elements in array are even.
Rethink about your operation.

Comment: Yes, i think you r right. Real question is that I have a data table & trying to covert it into the string array to break it into two parts.